# randomly regroup data in r ('regroup' in package 'LearnBayes' and 'caroline' didn't work)

Tags: r

Suppose I have a binomial distribution where n=12, p=0.2. I split this sample into 4 chunks(groups), each chunk has group size 3. Then I remove the output whose sum is equal to 0, and combine the remaining outputs into a new dataset. Here are some of my code:

```
set.seed(123)
sample1=rbinom(12,1,0.2)
chuck2=function(x,n)split(x,cut(seq_along(x),n,labels=FALSE))
chunk=chuck2(sample1,4)
newvector=c()
for (i in 1:4){
  aa=chunk[[i]]
  if (sum(aa)!=0){
    a.no0=aa
    newvector=c(newvector,a.no0)
  }
}
print(newvector)
```

and this is the result I got:

```
[1] 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
```

what I'm trying to do is randomly regroup this data, for example:

```
[1] 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
```

or

```
[1] 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0
```

......

I tried to use 'regroup' in package 'LearnBayes' and 'caroline', but it didn't work. Any hints please?

Comment: `sample(newvector)`?

Comment: @LyzandeR it works! Thanks a lot!